# Winforms TreeView Select Node At Design Time

Tags: winforms, treeview

I'm trying to create a `UserControl` based on a `TreeView` control. In that I need to handle node selection at design time. Unfortunately nodes do not get selected in Visual Studio at design time. Any suggestions/workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var info = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        treeView1.SelectedNode = info.Node;

        if (info.Node == null)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Use [TreeView.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sb88bz.aspx).

Comment: Hi. This still does not answer my primary question. To handle all this events AT DESIGN TIME. Test your answer. Nothing happens at design time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is such option using the `TreeNode Editor`:

[image]

You can open it in two ways:

1. Right Click on your **TreeView** control -> **Edit Nodes**

OR

2. From the **Properties** window go to **Behavior** section and look for **Nodes (Collection)**

Comment: etaiso: What I'm trying to do is switch panels in another container when a user selects node in the treeview. But unfortunately, VS is not allowing to select treenodes at design time.